# Can I connect a page to a taxonomy?

Tags: pages, taxonomy

I'm creating a website for a soccer club. It has news, reports and media custom post types. There you can connect the post to the Team taxonomy. But I also need to have a page for that team where I can add info, team photo etc.

Can I connect a page to a certain taxonomy? For example I got a page called "Team 1" and connect that to the taxonomy term "Team 1"?

If not what is the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register taxonomies for objects (such as posts & pages) like so:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_71914_assign_page_taxonomy' );

function wpse_71914_assign_page_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'taxonomy_name', 'page' );
}
```